# Set documents margins in JAVA

Tags: java

My output for my JAVA program goes into a FAX*****.doc, I am using the BufferedWriter class to write one line at a time to the file. When I open the file in word the margins are set to 1" all around. Leaving the page like this has undesirable effects on the format but if switched to .5" all around it is perfect.

Is there a way I can amend the margins to the document with JAVA?

I am generating word documents.

Comment: Are you generating Word `.doc` files, or Ascii text?

Answer (score 3):

You should try using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to handle .doc files.

Comment: I'm using a work computer and don't have rights to download stuff. I would have to contact our network admin, who still is working on my issue of not having my printers hooked up to the network. It's been 14 months of him trying to get them hooked up, I don't see this as an option right now.

Comment: correct, I don't even have permissions to remove desktop short-cuts :(